# Proof verification: If $gcd(n,9)=3$ then $gcd(n^2,9)=9$, $p∣n \implies p∣n^2$, $p∣n^2\implies p∣n$.

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

**1.** gcd$(n,9)=3$ then gcd$(n^2,9)=9$

**2.** Let $p$ be a prime and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, if $p∣n$ then $p∣n^2$.

**3.** Let $p$ be a prime and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, if $p∣n^2$ then $p∣n$.

I'm not sure about all of these proofs, here's what I've got at the moment.

**1.** By *Bézout's identity* (Given $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ not both 0, there exist $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ax+by=$gcd($a,b$)) there exist $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $nx+9y=3$=gcd($n,9$)
$nx+9y=3\implies (nx+9y)^2=3^2\implies n^2x^2+18nxy+81y^2=9\implies   
n^2(x^2)+9(2nxy+9y^2)=9$
and therefore gcd($n^2,9)=9$.

**2.** $p∣n \implies n=pk (k \in \mathbb{Z})\implies n^2=p^2k^2 \implies n^2=p(pk^2) \implies p∣n^2$.
Isn't this one just true even when p isn't a prime? I'm not seeing the relevance of p being a prime here unless I've done something wrong or it's just to compare to **3**.

**3.** $p∣n^2 \implies p∣n\cdot n \implies p∣n$ or $p∣n$ (by a prime divisibility property: Given a prime $p$, if $p∣ab$ then $p∣a$ or $p∣b$) $\implies p∣n$.
This one just feels too simple, have I missed out steps or have I done the whole thing incorrectly?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: In $(1)$ you need to explicitly justify "therefore gcd ... = 9$

Comment: 2,3 look fine. However in (1), Bezout identity is not an iff case. You cannot conclude that gcd($n^2$, 9)=9 by finding an linear combination of the form $an^2 + 9b = 9$.

Comment: 2) is simple.  $a|b$ and $b|c\implies a|c$ so $p|n$ and $n|n^2 so $p|n^2$.  3) is straight up euclides lemma.  If $p|ab$ then $p|a$ or $p|b$ so $p|n*n\implies $p|n$ or $p|n$. Proving euclids lemma must be proving.

Comment: For the reverse, that $\,9\mid\gcd(n^2,9)\,$ you can either use Bezout or, more generally use $\,a\mid b,c\Rightarrow\,a\mid \gcd(b,c)\,$ which is provable also by Bezout or other ways. In fact the gcd can be defined by the property that $\ c\mid a,b\iff c\mid \gcd(a,b).\,$ That is the definition used in more general number systems where there may be no ambient notion of "size" for "greatest"